# Stop imageview from stretching on certain devices

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-drawable, stretch

I have an activity xml that looks like this:

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/top"
        />

    <ScrollView
                ....
```

This basically shows a banner on top of the linearlayout with a scrollview below. The problem I'm having is that the image is stretched on certain devices. The source image width is 1080px (in the drawable and drawable-xxhdpi folder), 720px in drawable-xhdpi, 540px in drawable-hdpi and 480 in drawable-mdpi.

Am I forgetting something or giving them the wrong width? The image is stretched out vertically btw.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image sizes are wrong. The correct scales for image sized 480dp are

- `mdpi` 480px (x1)
- `hdpi` 720px (x1.5)
- `xhdpi` 960px (x2)
- `xxhdpi` 1440px (x3)

Also there's no need to have the image in `drawable` folder, Android will pick the best one from the listed.
See [this](https://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html) documentation for more info